# ngx-loading, Angular 4. Jhipster 4.8.2. Not Show Spinner

Tags: angular, spinner, jhipster

It sends you the steps to install the spinnner ngx-loading in my Jhipster 4.8.2 application, it does not give error and it seems it's ok, but it does not paint the spinner:

Install:

```
npm install --save ngx-loading
```

In app.module.ts:

```
import { LoadingModule } from 'ngx-loading';
....
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LayoutRoutingModule,
    Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: 'jhi', separator: '-' }),
    Crm482SharedModule,
    Crm482HomeModule,
    Crm482HomeRRHHModule,
    Crm482PrlModule,
    Crm482MainModule,
    Crm482AdminModule,
    Crm482AccountModule,
    Crm482EntityModule,
    SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot(),
    LoadingModule
    // jhipster-needle-angular-add-module JHipster will add new module here
],
```

main.component.html:

```
<simple-notifications [options]="optionsNotifications"></simple-notifications>
<ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '14px' }"></ngx-loading>
<jhi-page-ribbon></jhi-page-ribbon>
<div>
  <router-outlet name="navbar"></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<!--I tried to put it here and it's not going-->
<div class="card jh-card">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
</div>
<jhi-footer></jhi-footer>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
export class MyControllerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

public loading = false;
......
ngOnInit() {
  this.loading = true;
  ....
```

Comment: Is the ngx-loading package, and your requests both using HttpClientModule or HttpModule? HttpClientModule can't see requests that are made with HttpModule and vice versa.

Comment: The spinner is activated when I put this.loading = true; and it is activated when I put it to this.loading = false; . According to the example. Are you sure it depends on "HttpClientModule or HttpModule"?

Answer (score 1):

In main.component.ts ( no my component ):

```
public loading = false;

 ....

public loader(loading:boolean) {
 this.loading = loading;
}
```

In my.component.ts:

```
import {JhiMainComponent} from '../../../layouts/main/main.component';
....
this.jhiMainComponent.loader(true); // start
this.jhiMainComponent.loader(false); // finish
```

Comment: can i use it inside a  list's <li> tag?

Answer (score 0):

I just read through the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-loading) and realized you need to place

```
<ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{ backdropBorderRadius: '14px' }"></ngx-loading>
```

in your template component and not in the main app template. That would mean you need to write this for every component template along with a boolean variable in each component. (pretty tedious if you ask me)

I'd also recommend [this package](https://github.com/mpalourdio/ng-http-loader) since you only need to set it up once in your app component and it will work for all requests that are using HttpClientModule.

Comment: It does not work nor adding it to a specific component. The option you offer is not what I need, I want to put the spinner when I need it and remove it the same, and not depend on HttpClientModule, or anything.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Very good ngx-loading...

install:

```
npm i ngx-loading
```

in **app.module**:

```
import { LoadingModule, ANIMATION_TYPES } from 'ngx-loading';
imports:[
...
    LoadingModule.forRoot({
      animationType: ANIMATION_TYPES.wanderingCubes,
      backdropBackgroundColour: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)', 
      backdropBorderRadius: '4px',
      primaryColour: '#ffffff', 
      secondaryColour: '#ffffff', 
      tertiaryColour: '#ffffff'
  }),
...
]
```

in app.component.ts or in your component.ts **//REQUIRE**

```
loading: boolean = true;
```

in **app.component.htm**l or in your html component

```html
    <div class="my-container">
        <ngx-loading [show]="loading" [config]="{ 
                backdropBorderRadius: '14px', 
                backdropBackgroundColour: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.87)',
                fullScreenBackdrop: 'true',
                backdropBorderRadius: '10px',
                primaryColour: '#e2f000', 
                secondaryColour: '#e2f000', 
                tertiaryColour: '#e2f000'
             }">
        </ngx-loading>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late, but I had the same problem. You need to add the LoadingModule in the export array of your app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [

// loading spinner global settings
LoadingModule.forRoot({
  animationType: ngxLoadingAnimationTypes.chasingDots,
  backdropBackgroundColour: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
  backdropBorderRadius: '4px',
  primaryColour: '#ffffff',
  secondaryColour: '#ffffff',
  tertiaryColour: '#ffffff',
  fullScreenBackdrop: true
 })
 ],
  declarations: [],
 entryComponents: [],
 exports: [ LoadingModule ]
```